# Drop-down box dependent on the option selected in another drop-down box using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

how to get other parent drop downs value 
or  how to check child drop down value ?

This is  my example code:

```
<select id="dropdown1" class="dropdown">
    <option>val1</option>
    <option>val2</option>
</select>
<select id="dropdown2" class="dropdown">
    <option>val1</option>
    <option>val2</option>
</select>
<select id="dropdown3" class="dropdown">
    <option>val1</option>
    <option>val2</option>
</select>
```

this is my dropdown I want to check what is value of parent dropdown?

for e.g.
if I chose dropdown3 then what is value of dropdown 1 AND 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a variable that has all the dropdown ids:

```
var dropdowns = $( ".dropdown" ).map(function() {
    return $( this ).attr('id');
  });
```

Listen to onchange for each dropdown:

```
$('.dropdown').change((e) => {
    const dropdownId = e.target.id; // the changed dropdown
    const otherDropdowns = dropdowns.filter((index, id) => id !== dropdownId); // get the others
    const otherValues = otherDropdowns.map((index, id) => 
                        $('#' + id).find(":selected").val()); // get the values of others dropdowns
    console.log(otherValues);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/sw17L459/

Comment: if i want all dropdown values ?

Comment: Paste it in 'change' function:

const allDropdownValues = dropdowns.map((index, id) => 
                        $('#' + id).find(":selected").val());
console.log(allDropdownValues)

Comment: can you please help me how to get value of respective ids from element object?

Comment: jQuery.fn.init(4) ["val2", "val31", "val1", "val1", prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(4), context: document]0: "val2"1: "val31"2: "val1"3: "val1"context: documentlength: 4prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(4) ["dropdown1", "dropdown2", "dropdown3", "dropdown4", prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(4), context: document]__proto__: Object(0)